# Vim search pattern 'foo' but skip lines containing 'bar' without deleting any line

Tags: regex, search, vim, regular-language

I want to use search and highlight in vim using pattern match. My first search criteria is to look for a string `foo` in a line. My second search criteria is to skip all `foo` if the same line contains `bar` in it. I don't want to delete all lines containing `bar`. My first search criteria meets with following:

```
/foo
```

My second criteria is not meeting with:

```
/foo.*\(bar\)\@<!
```

Example text:

```
1 foo
2 foo bar xx
3 fooobar
4 bar
5 xxx
```

(here I want to highlight line numbers 1 only)

What I am missing here?

Reference: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html

Comment: Wait, does it mean you want a whole word match for `bar`?

Comment: No my example text was wrong, now it's fixed. I wanted to skip all lines with bar in it. But you figured out the solution any way :D

Comment: Ok, I rolled back my answer to Version 1.

Comment: You are too fast @WiktorStribiżew, thanks for your answer. I got cleared with multiple doubts on single answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/\(bar.*\)\@<!foo\(.*bar\)\@!
```

With very magic mode:

```
/\v(bar.*)@<!foo(.*bar)@!
```

**Details**

- `(bar.*)@<!` - a negative lookbehind: no `bar` followed with any 0 or more characters to the right of the current location
- `foo` - a word `foo`
- `(.*bar)@!` - a negative lookahead: no `bar` allowed after any 0 or more characters to the right of the current location.

Comment: I was aware of one thing that in my data bar always comes later, so I didn't use lookbehind. And my mistake was on keeping `.*` with `foo` instead of keeping within the atom bar. And second mistake was using `@<!` instead of `@!`.